# Using SharePoint version number in calculated column?

Tags: calculated-column, versioning

I'm trying to get the value of column "Version" in a calculated column. I'm not sure if it's a bug with SharePoint 2007 but every time a document is updated, the version number shown in the calculated column gets reset to "0" even if the formula is as simple as "=version".

I can see this question has already been asked on two other forums but so far there's no answer given:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/sharepoint2010general/thread/61e0bfb6-63d4-4e39-9ef1-2dc2ed910cf2

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1635126

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to the problem with using `=ID` on item creation.

In short, the version number *doesn't exist yet* when the formula's result is being recalculated (during the update). It's added to the item after the update has completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have versioning enabled, that will always return 0. On the other hand, updates are handled automatically, i assume via Event Handlers.