# Creating an Autonumber Column

Tags: column, number

Is there a way to create an autonumber column in the lists and libraries?
For example I want to have a list and when a user wants to add a new value, it automatically generates a new autonumber.

Comment: Can you just use the built in ID column?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When you create any list or Library a column named ID is created automatically and it is  Auto-number Column; And if you want to create your own autonumber column you can create it with Calculated Type of Column.

Comment: The link you specified to customise the autonumber is actually a question stating it doesn't work as expected using the calculated column.

Comment: hey Sorry i got wrong link..


try this link.. this shows how to create Autonumber Column in List..


http://sharepointinnovations.blogspot.in/2011/03/auto-generate-id-column-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: That looks...erm... pretty useless. Its just ID+1. Whats the advantage of that over just the existing ID column?

Comment: Unfortunately using `[ID]` in a calculated column doesn't work: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/46258/1529

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show this number on AllItems.aspx page, you can use xslt. In spd add a column at the beginning of the table for examaple and add there this formula: `position()`
It will show so-called 'id' of each item of the list