# Is there a way to show the document status inside a document library indicating if the document is Draft or Published

Tags: document-library, document, versioning, check-out, check-in

I have a SharePoint enterprise farm 2013 on-premises. and i have a team site which contain a document library. now for this document i define the following versioning settings:-

[image]

so currently my document can have a minor version with fraction (1.2, 2.5, etc..) OR major version. and when the document have a minor version i can chose to "Publish a major version". but my question is how i can define a status column inside my document library which will show if the document have "Draft" status when it have a minor version OR if the document have "Publish" status when it have a major version? is this possible?
i need something similar to the "Approval Status" field which will be automatically presented when i set the document library to "Require content approval for submitted items"..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably set up a calculated column that looks at the Version. Basically this finds the version, finds the decimal point and if the number after the decimal point is a 0, it's published, otherwise, it's a draft. I haven't tested this in SharePoint, but only in Excel and it worked.

```
=IF(RIGHT([Version], FIND(".",[Version])-1)="0", "Published", "Draft")
```

EDIT: Ack, it's one of the columns that gets updated afterwards. You may need to set a simple workflow to capture "Draft" or "Published" - [See here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29262/using-sharepoint-version-number-in-calculated-column)

Create a new column called "Draft/Published" where the default value is "Draft". Have a workflow that triggers on Item Modified in which the logic looks something like:

```
Pause for 1 minute
Find '.' in Version (Output to Variable: index)
Copy from Version, starting at index (Output to Variable: substring)
If substring equals 0 
   Set DraftStatus to "Published"
Else
   Set DraftStats to "Draft"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. now i tried to created a new calculated column and i define your formula. now if the document have a major version the status will be "Published" ,, but when the document have a minor version the status will be `#Name?` instead of "Draft" ... also if i refresh the page i will get `#Name?` even for major versions

Comment: Can you see if all the items have a version? Include the "Version" column in the view and refresh. Also, `#Name?` has something to with the syntax.

Comment: i actually only have a single document and it have a version = 5.0 and i chose to display the version inside the list view.. but i am getting this value `#Name?` inside the list view and inside the display form...

Comment: See my edit, it's the Version column that is updated AFTER commit.

Comment: so look like things are getting somehow complex assuming that i need to do these changes on many documents libraries.. so i can not rely on anu built-in features to get this working??

Comment: You could expose the Version in a list view and educate users that `.0` means Published and anything after means Draft